# Check value is numeric and no more than n digits

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I'm trying to add some validation to a VBA sub and I need to ensure the user enters a number and that it is no longer than the set limit, I'm pulling this in using a function as it varies depending on the team.

I can get the textlength

```
With Selection.Validation
    .Add Type:=xlValidateTextLength, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
    Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="0", Formula2:=ValidMaxLength
```

But obviously this can allow text.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible to convert the number to text (string) and then check for its length?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, throw in an `isnumeric` and a length:

```
If IsNumeric(Range("A1")) Then

    If Len(Range("A1").Value) < 3 Then

        'do stuff

    End If

End If
```

It's probably also best to check that it's not empty first, among other things. Since you only gave us a snippet, I'm only addressing a snippet.

Answer (score -1):

`Len` will not work here as it could pick up 1.0 as 3 digits and 100 as 3 digits. Since it is a number you'll simply need to check to see if the value is less than a certain amount (and likely more than 0 depending on your needs). Something like the code below should get you started.

```
Sub ValidateEntry()
    Dim rngToValidate As Range
    Dim val_UpperLimit As Double
    Dim val_LowerLimit As Double
    Set rngToValidate = Range("A1")
    val_UpperLimit = 100
    val_LowerLimit = 0

    If IsNumeric(rngToValidate) _
    And rngToValidate.Value < val_UpperLimit _
    And rngToValidate.Value > val_LowerLimit Then
        'passed validation
    Else
        'failed validation
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This is entirely true. **If** you don't want to count characters and only want to count digits, you'll need something that doesn't use `len`.

Comment: OP stated digits. Hence my response. And even if it was characters, since we are dealing with numbers, it is more reliable to validate within a range (unless you need to limit the numbers after the decimal point).